# OECD data error Error in download.file(path, destfile, method, quiet, mode, ...) :

Tags: r

I am attempting to download data from the OECD. When I run this code:

```
oecd.cpi.url <- list(
  core=list(dataset='MEI', indicator='CPGRLE01'),
  all.items=list(dataset='MEI', indicator='CPALTT01')
)

gbp.cpi <- get_dataset(oecd.cpi.url$all.items$dataset, 
                       filter=list(
                         LOCATION="GBR", 
                         INDICATOR=oecd.cpi.url$all.items$indicator
                       ))
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error in download.file(path, destfile, method, quiet, mode, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/MEI/all/all'
```

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried various solutions and cannot seem to determine what is wrong.

Comment: It seems likely that this is because [OECD stats have been discontinued](https://github.com/expersso/OECD/issues/30).

Comment: There are other issues remarking similar `get_dataset` errors (e.g., https://github.com/expersso/OECD/issues/28). This package has not seen an update in years, and in fact that user account on GH only has two logged "did something" events in the last several years, neither of which were with this project. I suspect somebody will need to adapt to the [new data explorer](https://data-explorer.oecd.org/).